# How to create Authkey for concoure server that can be used in API Calls to the concourse sever?

Tags: node.js, devops, concourse, devops-services, concourse-git-resource

```
 request(
        {
          url:'mysampleendpoint',
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Auth key from Browser (skymarshal_auth)',
          },
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
          if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            resolve(response.body);
          } else {
            reject(response.statusCode);
          }
        },
      );
```

I am using the above code to get the job status from my concourse server. The call works fine with no issues. However, the auth_key that I have used is the one that is generated by my browser (I Copied this when I did a simple get call to the concourse server from the browser). This key is expiring every 24 hours. How can I create a permanent key that I can use in my deployed app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can generate a permanent api key. A way to make this less painful is to write a small script that automatically pulls the token from your `~/.flyrc`, which will also last for 24 hours but gets updated whenever you log into fly.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I am new to concourse, Is there an example or doc that I can look into?

Comment: There's a pretty good tutorial by stark and wayne: https://concoursetutorial.com. It won't teach you everything but it will definitely give you a good foundation to start building pipelines and learning on your own. Also hanging out in the concourse discord is good. https://discord.gg/MeRxXKW